# Models does not appear

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces, laravel-8

> Class `App\Models\Booking` not found is appear

I have problem when I want to import class in Laravel 8.

in BookingController:
`use App\Models\Booking;`

in Booking.php:
`namespace App\Models\Models;`

but still it appear the error state that `App\Models\Booking` is not found. Please help me

Comment: Why do you use `App\Models\Models`?

Comment: because it automatic be like that when I make the booking.php

Comment: That doesn't mean that you cannot remove the second "Models" manually and move it one directory up. What is your "automatic" creation command?

Comment: when I try to remove the second Models it will appear this one Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.

Comment: That error doesn't seem to be caused by your change. It seems to be an additional problem.

Comment: Don't forget to adjust the file path so that it reflects the namespace/fully qualified name of the class.

Comment: Did you create your model using `php artisan make:model Booking`?

Comment: this one I'm not try yet.

Comment: What did you try instead?

Comment: okay. I have try. but then it state that a column was not found. its says that SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'updated_at' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `booking` (`id`, `name`, `email`, `phone_num`, `address`, `usertype`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2020461832, Mim, mimi@gmail.com, 0123456789, Bandar Seri Astana, opt3, 2021-07-15 09:58:48, 2021-07-15 09:58:48))

Comment: How did you "import" the models in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

In your case, in your `BookingController` try `use App\Models\Models\Booking;`

The default folder structure for models in Laravel 8 is `App/Models'. It's the best practice to stick to the default Laravel Architecture, but either way it works.

Comment: That's a workaround but not Laravel's default folder structure

Comment: Yes, true. But in his context means that all his models are placed in `App\Models\Models` so if he wants to change it, it must refactor the whole project namespaces where Models are used.

Comment: With a good IDE that doesn't take long but if they don't want to do that, your answer is not wrong.

Comment: true that. I personally use PHP storm as is configured to automaticly refactor everything. But i do not have much information what OP uses.. Anyway I'll update my answer a bit